# Exists - Not exists - Exclude records those are having status in 0 ignoring other status associated with that record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below is my data.

```
with cte as(
select 'A' name, 0 status
union all select 'A' name, 1 status
union all select 'B' name, 1 status
union all select 'C' name, 2 status
union all select 'D' name, 1 status
)
```

I want to get only `B, C, D` as output from the query. Lets say, `0` is `status-complete` & I want to ignore records associated with it.

This I am able to achieve using the `not in` clause as below.

```
select * from cte c
where c.name not in (select cf.name from cte cf where cf.status=0)
```

But I want to achieve this using `exists` or `not exists` clause in `where` condition.

Could you please share the logic ?

thanks,

Comment: If all that you want is ignore records with status=0 (which you interpet as status-complete) why is **select * from cte where status!=0** not sufficient?

Comment: @blackpen, 'A' has 0 as well as 1 status. In this case, your approach wont work as it will again fetch record 'A'. I want don't want 'A' in output.

Comment: If you really want to avoid A as well as other rows (non-A rows) with status=0, ... **select * from cte where (name!='A' and status!=0)** should work.

Comment: As a suggestion, please write down the exact rows that you want to see as output in your question (out of the 5 rows from input). Otherwise, I am afraid, it will turn into a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @blackpen, I understand your concern, but sometimes we are unable to provide the exact code or data screenshot due to data security concerns. That is why the best is to create a dummy scenario to get the answers in this case. Thank you : )

Comment: Did the query I gave you above did not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try with this:

```
SELECT * FROM cte c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT cf.name 
                  FROM cte cf WHERE c.name = cf.name AND cf.status = 0)
```

For this we don't need any column in the where clause because we are addressing that conditional column as comparison in WHERE of sub query.

Comment: This wasn't working in my actual scenario as I had inline tables joined with the outer apply clause. However, I achieved this using CTE & not exists clause. All answers below are correct. But first come first : ) thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

With **NOT EXISTS**

```
with cte as(
select 'A' name, 0 status
union all select 'A' name, 1 status
union all select 'B' name, 1 status
union all select 'C' name, 2 status
union all select 'D' name, 1 status
)
select * from cte out where NOT EXISTS 
(select inn.name from cte inn WHERE out.name = inn.name and inn.status=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @tbl1 AS TABLE
(
   Name VARCHAR(50),
   Status INT
)

INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES('A',0)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES('A',1)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES('B',1)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES('C',1)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES('D',1)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES('E',0)
```

With **Not EXISTS:**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM @tbl1 T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT T2.Name FROM @tbl1 T2  WHERE T2.Status=0 AND T1.Name=T2.Name)
```

With **EXISTS:**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM @tbl1 T1
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT T2.Name FROM @tbl1 T2  WHERE  T1.Name=T2.Name AND T1.Status=1  GROUP BY T2.Name having count(T2.Status)=1 )
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: You can't conclude the having condition in the exists clause due to the incompleteness of the question, multiple status except 0 can exists at the same time.

Comment: yes you are right, i have add where condition, is it ok now?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
with cte as(
select 'A' name, 0 status
union all select 'A' name, 1 status
union all select 'B' name, 1 status
union all select 'C' name, 2 status
union all select 'D' name, 1 status
) 
Select * from cte c
where NOT EXISTS  (select 1 from cte cf where cf.status=0 AND c.name = cf.name)
```

Comment: OP says that he wants to get rows with status!=0. Could you explain why are you joing two cte tables for that?